# PHP Email Cron Job

Tags: php, email, cron

I am developing a php script where i want to send automated mails to users. 
I successfully implement a cron job with php script, which checks out a php mail queue table for pending mails. 
The script is working fine, but the cron job is working strangely, It sends the mail to users, but 3 or 4 at a time. I wanted to send mail only once. how can i achieved it ?

My cron job checks mail queue table for every 2 minutes.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you should post some code :)

Comment: Please, post your crontab line and some brief of your PHP code

Comment: Is your table updated correctly? In other words, are the mails which get send more than 1 time, correctly updated with a status 'Sent' or something similar?

Comment: Show some code, or do you actually think that the text you wrote is enough to tell you what you did wrong?

Comment: @BenFransen Yes, I am checking my tables, it only have one entry per pending mail.

Comment: It may happens because time of script execution is more than 2 mins, or you have more than one row for each email. Did you mark email in queue as 'sent'? Is script checks for this mark?

Comment: And of Course I am maintaing sent_mail field and after sending mail I am also updating this field!!

Comment: @ashutosh obviously you're not

Answer (score 2):

Every 2 minutes?
My guess is the previous cron job doesn't finish and a second one starts, that's why it sends multiple emails to the same person or account.

Try decreasing the frequency to every hour or so

Comment: You may create pid file as well to check if script is still running, and if it is - do not run it again

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a field in table like `sent_status`.

At the time of fetching mails, use sql WHERE clause like `sent_status = 0` and update this field by email id when mail sent to user by `sent_status = 1`.

So a single user can not get mails in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

Add some code similar to how a PID file works:

```
$path = '/path/to/pid/file';

// Check for PID file's existance, if found exit.
if (file_exists($path))
{
    echo 'PID File Exists';
    exit;
}

file_put_contents($path, '1'); // Create PID file

// Execute your code

unlink($path); // Delete the PID file
```

A couple notes:

- If your script fatal errors then your script will never run again, you need to ideally check the [last modified time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) of the file
- Using WGET to run crons is BAD, your script will still time out as if you were running it via the browser. Run it using the PHP CLI instead.